# Ruby - select items from an array of tuples using items from an other array containing a single field

Tags: ruby

I'm using Ruby and I try to select tuples stored in an Array, using items from the other Array as criteria.

```
list = [{field1:value1,field2:valueA},...,{field1:valuen,field2:valueZ}]

criteria = [sel1,sel2,sel3,sel4,...]
```

What is the most efficient way to create a new Array of tuples (a subset of a list), with `field1==criteria[i]` (any element from criteria)?

I already tried with `.each` combined with `.find`? but it takes a while because the list is a quite large Array.

Comment: Do you have a workable example?

Answer (score 0):

```
# Set is more efficient than Array for this use-case
require 'set'
criteria = Set.new [sel1,sel2,sel3,sel4,...]

list = [{field1:value1,field2:valueA},...,{field1:valuen,field2:valueZ}]
result = list.select {|i| criteria.include? i[:field1] }
```

Comment: This is perfectly working.  Thank you vm for this, Igneus.

Comment: @Luc The StackOverflow way of saying "this solution works perfectly, thanks" is marking the answer as accepted ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to try this... you might want to do some benchmarks.

```
subset = list.select{ |h| (criteria & h.keys).any? }
```

Comment: Thank you vm for this alternative solution.  Appreciated, Steve

Answer (score 0):

Thank you vm.
I tried  both  and the solution proposed by Igneus seems to be the best for my situation.
It runs in less than 1 second i/o about 7 minutes with my ".each" loop.
Wonderful !!!